# How to inject an interface into the constructor of a DbContext at design time ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I need to pass an instance of the `ICurrentTenantRepository` interface into the constructor of my `AppDbContext` class at design time, but I don't know how to do it. I've done a lot of research on the subject and haven't found anything that helps me...

If I don't create it at design time, it works normally, but if I create it at design time, I need to create a new instance of `AppDbContext` and at this point I don't know how to do it.

Does anyone know how to help me?

Thanks!

[image]

```
public sealed class AppDbContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{       
    private readonly ICurrentTenantRepository _currentTenantRepository;
    public string CurrentTenantId { get; set; }
    public string CurrentTenantConnectionString { get; set; }

    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options, ICurrentTenantRepository currentTenantRepository) : base(options)
    {
        _currentTenantRepository = currentTenantRepository;

        if (_currentTenantRepository is not null)
        {
            CurrentTenantId = _currentTenantRepository.TenantId;
            CurrentTenantConnectionString = _currentTenantRepository.ConnectionString;
        }

        ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    }       
}

public  class AppDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>
{
    public AppDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args) // neccessary for EF migration designer to run on this context
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

        return new AppDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}

 public interface ICurrentTenantRepository
 {
     string? ConnectionString { get; set; }
     string? TenantId { get; set; }
     public Task<bool> SetTenant(string tenant);
 }

 public class CurrentTenantRepository : ICurrentTenantRepository
{
    private readonly TenantDbContext _context;
    public string? ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string? TenantId { get; set; }

    public CurrentTenantRepository(TenantDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<bool> SetTenant(string tenant)
    {
        var tenantInfo = await _context.Tenants.Where(x => x.Id == tenant).FirstOrDefaultAsync(); // check if tenant exists
        if (tenantInfo != null)
        {
            TenantId = tenant;
            ConnectionString = tenantInfo.ConnectionString; // optional connection string per tenant (can be null to use default database)
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Tenant invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's stopping you from doing `return new AppDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options**, new CurrentTenantRepository()**);`?

Comment: You suggested creating a new object new CurrentTenantRepository... I didn't know you could do it like that... I believe that if I do "new CurrentTenantRepository(new TenantDbContext(new DbContextOptions<TenantDbContext>()))" it works...

Comment: There's no DI in your use case, as it were. And DI is nothing magic, it is creating objects somehow and you can do the same.

Comment: A DbContext *is* a Unit-of-Work already. It doesn't need any "repository" CRUD classes, it's a (far, far) higher-level abstraction. Like all ORMs it's job is to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables.

Comment: I suspect the *real* question is how to use EF Core in a multi-tenant application. This is covered in the docs, in [EF Core - Multitenancy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy) which shows how to handle different multi-tenancy strategies. The current tenant is provided by an injected `ITenantService` and may come from eg an HttpContext, a cookie or credential-to-tenant mapping. Depending on the strategy, a different connection or query filter can be used to restrict the tenant records

Answer (score -1):

Thank you @Tanveer Badar

Solution:

```cs
return new AppDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options, new CurrentTenantRepository(new TenantDbContext(new DbContextOptions<TenantDbContext>())));
```

Comment: DbContext already is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work, it doesn't need "repository" CRUD classes. If you have to inject a single-entity "repository" with another DbContext into yet another DbContext, something is very, very wrong